# Проблема с транзакцией фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Как выглядит приложение :
По одной из выборочных вариантов меню пользователь переходит на первый либо второй фрагмент.
Приложение падает, я поняла так что причина в том что он не может найти контейнер.
На месте  R.id.fragmentContainer должен стоять ID контейнера фрагмента, но я без понятия где его объявить или искать.  Вот моя функция по смене фрагментов

```
  private fun changeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name).commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В родительской активности нужно добавить FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

и по логике все должно заработать правильно, общий вид:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Фрагмент 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Фрагмент 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Фрагмент 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

плюс можно перенести `fragmentManager` переменную сразу в транзакцию если вы ее нигде больше не используете. [Доп инфа](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-replace.php)